# sshguard - must a user declare behavior rules?

Tags: ssh, security, iptables

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415655/258010) I understand that `sshguard` does include a default behavior that should suit most users, at least those with minimal webserver environments, yet it wasn't clear to me from the [documentation](https://www.sshguard.net/docs/setup/) and from [this article](https://www.unixmen.com/block-ssh-brute-force-attacks-using-sshguard/) if one **must** change the defaults or add directives upon them.

Must a user declare behavior rules for `sshguard`? Isn't it shipped with a default set of rules (similar to CSF-LFD)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All what you will need to do is:

- Setup your iptables for ports managed by sshguard as writen in article.
- Review defaults for sshguard in config. You will need to check if default values fits your server needs. Ex. number of failed auths on ssh before adding ip drop to iptables. Or time for which the rule should be there.

Most of those should be fine but when you are running service where auth failures are quite common like webmail where user is trying to remember his password by trying it 10times or 20 times you should consider checking the config.